# Does Winsock support IPv6 extension headers?

Tags: winsock, ipv6

Is it possible to look at (and modify) IPv6 extension headers with Winsock using C/ C++? What API's allow us to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPv6 headers are not received using Raw Sockets on Winsock. As [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says

> For IPv6 (address family of AF_INET6), an application receives
>   everything after the last IPv6 header in each received datagram
>   regardless of the IPV6_HDRINCL socket option. The application does not
>   receive any IPv6 headers using a raw socket.

In other words, it's not possible to receive and modify IPv6 headers (or extension headers) using Winsock.